# Netsuite / Freemarker - splitting item description by line is not working

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

Anyone who can help why the below code is not working.
This is my code:

```
 <#list item.description?split("\n", 'r') as desc>
   <tr> 
      <td align="left" colspan="23">${desc}</td>
   </tr>
 </#list>
```

I am editing an advance PDF/HTML template in Netsuite. I need to split the item description as 1 line per row. I wanted to split them like this because we have a case like for 1 item, there is a super long description and what happens is, instead of printing the items 1,2,3 in continuous flow, the print only displays 1 item in page 1 and the next item is in page 2 even though item 1 only occupied 10% of page 1. for item 2 (with very long description, it did occupy 100% of page 2).

If the code above is working correctly, then item 1 and item 2 should be printed on page 1 and some of the descriptions of item 2 should be on page 2.

I tried changing the code to `<#list item.description?split(".") as desc>` and it worked.

Comment: Where you're using the regex flag, you might need to escape the backslash there (`"\\n"`).

Comment: I guess `item.description` doesn't contain "hard" line breaks, and it's just the browser that warps the text at page edge. If so, those line breaks aren't yet present where FreeMarker runs.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Thanks. I tried it and it also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found what works. Instead of "\n" or "\n", I use the br tag to split the item.descripiton.

```
<#list description?split("<br /><br />") as desc>
```